# Таблица с датой на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Как сделать так, чтобы таблица не рисовалась каждую секунду, а изменлись значения в ней?

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

function getInfo() {
    let date = new Date(),
        year = +date.getFullYear(),
        month = +(date.getMonth() + 1),
        day = +date.getDate(),
        hour = +date.getHours(),
        minutes = +date.getMinutes(),
        second = +date.getSeconds();


    let table = document.createElement("table");

    table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>Год</td><td>' + year + '</td></tr>';
    table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>Месяц</td><td>' + month + '</td></tr>';
    table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>День</td><td>' + day + '</td></tr>';
    table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>Час</td><td>' + hour + '</td></tr>';
    table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>Минута</td><td>' + minutes + '</td></tr>';
    table.innerHTML += '<tr><td>Секунда</td><td>' + second + '</td></tr>';


    document.body.appendChild(table);
};


setInterval(getInfo, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getInfo() {
  let table = document.getElementById('timetable');
  if (!table) {
    table = document.createElement("table");
    table.innerHTML = `<tr><td>Год</td><td id="table-year"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Месяц</td><td id="table-month"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>День</td><td id="table-day"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Час</td><td id="table-hour"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Минута</td><td id="table-minutes"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Секунда</td><td id="table-seconds"></td></tr>`;
    table.id = 'timetable';
    document.body.appendChild(table);
  }
  let date = new Date(),
    year = +date.getFullYear(),
    month = +(date.getMonth() + 1),
    day = +date.getDate(),
    hour = +date.getHours(),
    minutes = +date.getMinutes(),
    seconds = +date.getSeconds();
  let dateObj = {
    year,
    month,
    day,
    hour,
    minutes,
    seconds
  };
  for (let key in dateObj) {
    document.getElementById('table-' + key).textContent = dateObj[key];
  }

};


setInterval(getInfo, 1000);
```